# How to count distinct timestamps within an embedded string?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a column in my table that gives me this value

```
[{"ts":"2018-10-28T01:43:44.000"},{"ts":"2018-10-28T01:45:06.000"}]
```

pretty much what they are, are timestamps from when a user opened an email. I would like to get a count of how many times they opened the email by counting each time stamp within this string. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: Will the `JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH` function work? Can you provide more context? This may be simple to do inside the query itself.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH.html

Comment: This does the job as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the string-method, which is pretty simple in this case:

```
select length(str) - length(replace(str, '"ts":', '1234'))
```

The replacement string is one character shorter, so this has the effect of counting the number of occurrences of `"ts":`.

Comment: Wow that did the job! could you explain how that '1234' works though? I am a little bit confused about that

Comment: It is literally taking the entire JSON string, calculating its length, then replacing every instance of `"ts":` ( 5 characters) with `1234` (4 characters) and then calculating the new length of the string. Since it will remove 1 character, this is essentially like counting a 1 for each entry of `"ts":`.

Comment: However, if you have a record like `[{"ts":""}]`, that will still count as 1. I don't know if that's what you want or if that's possible in your data, but something to keep in mind.

Comment: A count of the records can still probably be done within your query. I'm not familiar with Amazon Redshift's query syntax, but counting results is fairly basic functionality.